When using defer in routes in laravel, a php fatal error is returned
Im playing around with defer in laravel. I have this:
Route::get('testing', function () {
    defer(function(){
        //          sleep(3);
        Log::info('sleeping');
    })
        ->always(); // Will always run defer once executed

    return 'Rtoufasdfa';
});

Im getting this in my sail terminal.
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Swoole\Error: API must be called in the coroutine in /var/www/html/routes/web.php:94
  Stack trace:
2024-11-08 23:15:05,688 INFO reaped unknown pid 1093 (exit status 255)
 2024-11-08 23:15:05,688 INFO reaped unknown pid 1094 (exit status 255)
 #0 /var/www/html/routes/web.php(94): defer()

anyone familiar with defer whove ran into this issue?

It suggests that the route/defer must me called in a Swoole\Coroutine. This thread may help you:.

This means it looks like defer() requires a coroutine context, not available in standard Laravel routes.
If one needs to run some tasks at the end of a request,
try using register_shutdown_function since this function works outside coroutines:
Route::get('testing', function () {
    register_shutdown_function(function() {
        Log::info('sleeping');
    });

    return 'Rtoufasdfa'; 
});


The error Swoole\Error: API must be called in the coroutine indicates that the defer function is being called outside of a Swoole coroutine context. Swoole’s defer function is designed to run cleanup tasks at the end of a coroutine, so it needs to be called within a coroutine.
In Laravel, if you’re using Sail with Swoole, your code execution might not always be in a coroutine by default, especially in route closures. To solve this issue, you can make sure your code runs inside a coroutine.
Here’s how you can wrap your code inside a coroutine for testing purposes:
use Swoole\Coroutine;

Route::get('testing', function () {
    Coroutine\run(function () {
        defer(function () {
            Log::info('sleeping');
        });

        // Your main code logic here
        return 'Rtoufasdfa';
    });
});

If you need a more permanent solution for using coroutines within a controller or other parts of the application, you may want to use a Swoole-compatible package, such as swooletw/laravel-swoole, which can handle coroutine context automatically. Then, define your logic within a controller, ensuring it’s compatible with Swoole’s coroutine system.
With this approach, the code in defer will execute correctly inside a coroutine, and the always() call should work as expected.
Let me know if this helps resolve your error!

This is because of a conflict with swoole's defer() function.
See this issue:
https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/52800
You can use the Concurrency facade instead.
Route::get('testing', function () {
    \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Concurrency::defer(function(){
    //          sleep(3);
    Log::info('sleeping');
    })
    ->always(); // Will always run defer once executed

    return 'Rtoufasdfa';
});

